# Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module 'classNames'

Tags: reactjs, npm, browserify

When I run `npm start` on a react project I get following error:

```
Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module 'classNames' from '/home/nuwan/Nuclei/rollingright/location-admin']
stream: 
 Labeled {
 _readableState: 
  ReadableState {
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: [],
    length: 0,
    pipes: [Object],
    pipesCount: 1,
    flowing: true,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    objectMode: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    resumeScheduled: false },
 readable: true,
 domain: null,
 _events: 
  { end: [Object],
    error: [Object],
    data: [Function: ondata],
    _mutate: [Object] },
 _eventsCount: 4,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 _writableState: 
  WritableState {
    highWaterMark: 16,
    objectMode: true,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: true,
    ended: true,
    finished: true,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    buffer: [],
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: true,
    errorEmitted: false },
 writable: true,
 allowHalfOpen: true,
 _options: { objectMode: true },
 _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
 _streams: [ [Object], [Object] ],
 length: 2,
 label: 'deps' } }
```

I searched for the web and didn't found any solutions for this issue.
Can anyone suggest me what would be wrong, I am using ubuntu Os.